# Django module not found error: email verification

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-email

I'm new to python and Django so sorry in advance if I'm missing something obvious.
I'm trying to install the module 'django-email-verification' following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEdrtb9RMHM&list=PLQUG56-XNEGQ82lNQRRvcwIYhX9wSqNaF&index=4&t=300s) to add email verification to my users.
I've already done the pip install while on my virtual enviroment, and tried adding it to INSTALLED_APPS in settings, but still getting error.

[Here is an image of the error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR9jM.png)

I have tried

```
 pip install django-email-verification==0.0.4, 
 pip install django-email-verification
 pip3 install django-email-verification
```

And in settings with

```
'django-email-verification',
'django_email_verification',
```

It says it's already installed, but still no module named like it. Am I missing something?

Edit: After using pip freeze it shows this:

[image]

Edit2: screenshot using django_email_verification
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Double check your `settings.py` with what the video shows [here](https://youtu.be/KEdrtb9RMHM?t=140).

Comment: `pip freeze` your interpreter which you use to run the project to make sure you installed the package correctly.

Comment: Can you show your views where you import this, i.e., `from ... import ...`?

Comment: @raphael I'm not importing it anywhere since it doesn't work on INSTALLED_APPS in settings

Comment: Okay, I just tried it, and it works flawlessly on my machine.  Can you reproduce the error where you have `'django_email_verification'` (with UNDERSCORES) in your INSTALLED_APPS, and show the trace for that.  Right now, the error you show is for having `'django-email-verification'` (Dashes instead of underscores) in the INSTALLED_APPS.  I get *exactly* the same error you show when using the dashes, `-` instead of the underscores, `_`, as the answer by @Blind2k already shows.  I understand the confusion.  They want you to pip install with dashes, but use undescores in the settings.py.

Comment: @raphael just edited to add the screenshot. Thanks for your time btw!

Comment: According to that screenshot, you're mixing two different installations of Python.  `C:\Python310` and `C:\Users\choco\Desktop\TFG\operRating\Backend\venv\...`.  Don't do that.

Answer (score 4):

Since the module is called "django_email_verification", you should add only it.

```
   'django-email-verification', # Remove this one
    'django_email_verification',
```

The interpreter iterates one setting after the other and continues or returns.

Comment: Yeah, what I meant is that I tried with both versions, and none worked

Comment: @joel have you double-checked: that you are using the right terminal/virtual environment, properly configuring the IDE for the right interpreter, and updating your OS/IDE/Python/Django (latest: 4.2.1)/pip?

Comment: For pip I have 23.1.2, as for python 3.10.7 and django 4.1.4, and I only have one virtual enviroment in this project. Should I update all of them?